# Move XML element using XDT

Tags: xml, xdt-transform, xdt

Is there a way to move an XML element, including all of its content, inside another element using XDT?

For example, I'd like to transform the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
    <b someAttribute="someValue">someContent</b>
</a>
```

into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
    <c>
        <b someAttribute="someValue">someContent</b>
    </c>
</a>
```

by moving the `b` element inside of the newly created `c` element. I was hoping that something like the following would work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <c xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <b xdt:Locator="XPath(/a/b)" xdt:Transform="an appropriate transform" />
    </c>
</a>
```

But AFAIK there is no transform that would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported, as answered in [Web.config transforms - surrounding elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466161/web-config-transforms-surrounding-elements), but this question does offer one workaround.